# Wordpress - Admin ajax error - An error has occurred. Please reload the page and try again

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a footer widget but get this error:

> An error has occurred. Please reload the page and try again.

The widget trying to post to /admin-ajax.php and get this response back:

```
{"success":false,"data":"widget_setting_too_many_options"}
```

Any idea how to solve this? I wanna use the plugin for a footer and attach a menu widget to it.

wordpress version is 4.7.3

Answer (score -1):

Removing the following section from file wp-includes/class-wp-customize-widgets.php solve this error

```
if ( 0 !== $this->count_captured_options() ) {
  if ( $this->count_captured_options() > 1 ) {
        $this->stop_capturing_option_updates();
        return new WP_Error( 'widget_setting_too_many_options' );
  }

  $updated_option_name = key( $this->get_captured_options() );
  if ( $updated_option_name !== $option_name ) {
    $this->stop_capturing_option_updates();
    return new WP_Error( 'widget_setting_unexpected_option' );
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 I think it's not a good idea to fix this by messing around with wordpress' internal code as you might break something else